# How to remove multiple rows based off of a column value in excel?

Tags: excel

How would one be able to remove a row based off of column value in excel?
In this case the removing multiple rows when the `Consumption` column does not have a value of 0.

For Example:

```
Start           End            Consumption
4/3/2012 2:30   4/3/2012 2:45   165
4/3/2012 2:45   4/3/2012 3:00   0
4/3/2012 3:00   4/3/2012 3:15   105
4/3/2012 3:15   4/3/2012 3:30   0
4/3/2012 4:15   4/3/2012 4:30   125
```

For Example:

```
Start           End            Consumption
4/3/2012 2:45   4/3/2012 3:00   0
4/3/2012 3:15   4/3/2012 3:30   0
```

Assuming there are 1000+ rows. What would be the most efficient way of doing this on excel
?

Comment: This would be fairly easily accomplished by a macro but one might add a filter to the consumption column and then delete all visible cells just as well.

Comment: @SilentRevolution, Thanks for your answers. How would I create such filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select a cell in your data range then click the filter button, once you've clicked the filter button, little drop down icons should appear on your headers. When you click thee dropdown you have various options but if you sort lowest to highest, you can then simply delete the rows which are greater than 0.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have just clicked 0 on the drop down menu, under number filters.

Comment: That only hides the rows and doesn't delete them, if you clear the filter then the rows show up again.